# Save redis client list to file

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I'm investigating issues with redis and a high number of clients (above the default limit of 10000). Although the `CLIENT LIST` command works fine, one can't do much with it. I would like to save it to a file, so as to run some metrics (sort by ip, time, etc).

Unfortunately, it's not possible with redis-cli, since `CLIENT LIST > ~/clients.txt` throw a syntax error.
Is there a way to save client list for later use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it from the terminal shell,

```
>>> redis-cli "CLIENT LIST" > ~/clients.txt
```